# Создание волновой анимации

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, css-animation

Я пытаюсь сделать анимацию похожую на аудио волны. Что не так с этим кодом?

Пытаюсь применить - `translate to scale`, но это не помогает.
 Может ли кто-нибудь, дать мне ссылку на некоторые примеры анимации?

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation: wave 2s linear infinite;
}
.a1 {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.a2 {
  animation-delay: .2s;
}
.a3 {
  animation-delay: .4s;
}
.a4 {
  animation-delay: .6s;
}
.a5 {
  animation-delay: .8s;
}
@keyframes wave {
  0%, 50%, 75%, 100% {
    height: 5px;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    height: 30px;
    transform: translateY(15px);
    background-color: palevioletred;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="a1"></span>
  <span class="a2"></span>
  <span class="a3"></span>
  <span class="a4"></span>
  <span class="a5"></span>
</div>
```

Перевод вопроса: [Making a wave animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304159/making-a-wave-animation/33304437#33304437) @[LCTS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4981138/lcts)

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304159/making-a-wave-animation/33304437#33304437

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете удалить перемещение элементов вверх и вниз, анимировав свойство `transform: translateY`, вместо высоты элементов.
А также использовать функцию `scaleY()`, чтобы увеличить высоту элементов по оси `Y`.

Пример кода:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation: wave 2s linear infinite;
}
.a1 {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.a2 {
  animation-delay: .2s;
}
.a3 {
  animation-delay: .4s;
}
.a4 {
  animation-delay: .6s;
}
.a5 {
  animation-delay: .8s;
}
@keyframes wave {
  0%, 50%{
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  25% {
    transform: scaleY(4);
    background-color: palevioletred;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="a1"></span>
  <span class="a2"></span>
  <span class="a3"></span>
  <span class="a4"></span>
  <span class="a5"></span>
</div>
```

Перевод ответа: [Making a wave animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304159/making-a-wave-animation/33304437#33304437) @web-tiki